# How would I define a mix of Objective-C method parameters?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to do something like this in my program:

```
[obj list error:&error];
```

But when I try to define the prototype/method, I get compile errors.

I've tried the following definitions:

```
-(void)list error:(NSError **)error;

-(void)list:() error:(NSError **)error;
```

nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the space between `list` and `error` in the method signature. If this is the prototype -

```
-(void) list_error:(NSError **)error;
```

`list_error` expects a pointers address to be passed to it. So, this should work.

```
[obj list_error:&ptr] ; // Assuming ptr is of type NSError* and is initialized.
```

---

I think, you are getting confused when to send more than one parameter to a method. Its simple. Method signature should be -

**- ( return_type ) splitOne:(type) arg1 splitTwo:(type) arg2 ;**

`-` indicates instance method. Same is the case for class method too but substitued a `+` instead of `-`. And so on the method name can be splitted.

Taking an example of fraction, to set a fraction it needs both numerator and denominator. So,

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n setDenominator: (int) d ;
```

And to call it -

```
[ obj setNumerator:10 setDenominator:20 ] ;
```

**What is the need to split the method name ?**

Normally, in `C` this function prototype would be -

```
void setFraction( int a, int b );
```

But when seeing the prototype, it isn't obvious whether `a` is numerator or denominator and is the same with `b`. That is the reason, why in *Objective-C* method name **may be** splitted into parts. In the above example of *Objective-C*, both the `setNumerator` and `setDenominator` forms the method name. And when calling, it's quite obvious to the user, the parameter being passed is what. Hope it helps to resolve your problem.

Comment: The original prototype for the list method was as follows:
    
    -(void)list;

But now i want to support passing a referent to NSError, hence the space in my prototype:

    -(void)list error:(NSError **)error

I hope this helps to clarify my question.

Comment: There should be no space in a single method name. If you need to support `list` to receive an argument then `-(void)list :(NSError**)error;` is the way to it.

Comment: To tell it in terms of **C**, it is overloading the function `list`.